# Brown PCB Traces - Explanation?

Tags: pcb

I just received my first PCB back from the manufacturer. After soldering on the SMT components I found that the board works absolutely fine. The only thing I'm puzzled about is that both the ground pour and the traces are a brown color and not the green I would expect it to be since I specified a green solder mask. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I've tested the resistance of the ground pour between two points and it is not conductive, so this does not appear to be pure copper. However, since this is my first PCB I am really puzzled about the brown color. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Have you asked the PCB supplier?

Comment: No, I didn't want to sound like an idiot if there's a really obvious explanation...

Comment: You should take it up with them, the solder mask is obviously the wrong colour. Who is the supplier?

Comment: That looks like the solder mask isn't a full print, but almost something that is deposited only on the copper after a mask is placed on the copper portions not meant to be masked.  I would also look and see if your mask layer gerber is like this or has full coverage where there isn't copper.

Comment: I didn't send them Gerber files - I just sent them the Eagle .brd file since they accept that format. Could I have missed a setting in Eagle for the solder resist layer that would have caused this?

Comment: The supplier is Würth Elektronik. I don't really mind about the  color by the way, I'm just curious why it is this way. And if I do have any solder mask at all or if this is something else.

Comment: Not sure on the Eagle questions.  Generally soldermask is a negative image.  i.e. You only show in your EDA tool the portions that are NOT to be solder masked. I would find it odd that you would have accidentally specified not masking uncoppered board.  I wonder if they applied it improperly, so it only bonded to the copper.  Or it is a new low cost process.  I would worry about long term corrosion resistance on the edges of the traces possibly exposed to moisture.

Comment: Well I just checked in Eagle and I can confirm that the tStop layer only shows over the pads, not anywhere else like the edge of the board.

Comment: Overall, PCB manufacturing is pretty complex, so there's not really any stupid questions. Don't be afraid to call the PCB supplier, they will usually not hesitate to call you in a similar manner ("did you actually mean to have the silk screen in the middle layer or should we move it to the top?").

Comment: I think your next course of action is to contact the manufacturer and see what they say. I would be very interested to see what they say happened.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like they used clear solder mask. If there was no solder mask, the gold would have plated all over the copper.

Your photo is not clear enough to confirm that, but try looking closely at an oblique angle and see if you can see a small gap between a gold-plated pad and a clear shiny layer on the board.

Comment: Ah, that would make more sense.  There isn't missing solder mask where there is not copper, it just isn't easy to see in the photo.

Comment: I have looked at a lot of different angles under the light and I can't identify a clear shiny layer. I would have thought that if there was NO solder mask, though, that I would get zero resistance when I put my multimeter on two points of the ground pour. I'm a newbie though, so what do I know.

Comment: It looks like the copper is oxidized (which would also show high resistance). But I don't know how you could do that *and* have an ENIG finish... I only see options for green soldermask on the Wurth site.

Answer (score 3):

Soldermask is nearly always somewhat translucent, so the color over the copper ends up a much darker shade than over bare areas of the board.

It looks to me like the soldermask they used on this board is a very feint/translucent shade of green (maybe someone accidentally mixed some clear soldermask with the green stuff) and/or is applied very thin. So on the copper areas the fient green of the soldermask combines with the pinkish color of the copper to produce a brown, while in the non-copper areas you see a very feint green.